# Copy files from local to remote machine from windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have hostname/(IPAddress), username and password of the remote machine. I want to copy a folder to remote machine from local. eg. from D:/ of local to (public)Z:/ of remote machine.

I tried :

net use \IPAddress\c$ /user:domain\username password 
xcopy “D:\Test1” “\IPAddress\Z:\Folder” /X /H /E /V

and it says FileNotFound Test1.

I think the connection is made as the first command executes succesfully but some problem when i try access local folder.

Comment: Because it thinks Test1 is a file and not a folder. Try adding a trailing '\' at the end of source dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write “D:\Test1\*.*”